# Python Django from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

Tags: python, django, consumer

Python Django
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.3.12:8000/room/74b38da601c8d3bce0dcfd269d72fc4c0c5c63d7abe0d74599a6c0cc39a110f9/' failed:

[image]

> [20/Jul/2023 11:13:34] "GET
> /room/0ab774881c5b30fc126ad1a0acc4d4202228982ddbbeb44cfaf92f2cc952e141/
> HTTP/1.1" 404 6463

I checked the urls,find there don't have /room; But,routing.py:

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [re_path(r'room/(?P<group>\w+)/$',consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),re_path(r'enroom/(?P<group>\w+)/$',consumers.ChatEnConsumer.as_asgi()),re_path(r'chart/(?P<group>\w+)/$',consumers.ChartConsumer.as_asgi()),re_path(r'user_actual_line/(?P<group>\w+)/$', consumers.UserActualLineConsumer.as_asgi()),]
```

So I suspect something is wrong with websocketconsumer